# Java Swing: JTable tableChanged does not work after model is updated

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

On load, my JTable has 2 columns - . So its a string in the first column and a checkbox in the second column. When I click on the checkbox tableChanged is fired and I can print the row data that was selected.

I need to change the table data when user selects a new category in the dropdown.
When the table data is updated, and I click on the checkbox the tableChanged is no longer fired.
This is what I have:
This is how I am updating the table data:

```
 comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    String t = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    if (t.equals("survey2")) {
                        String[] columnNames = { "Volume Name", "Select" };
                        Object[][] data = { { "pt1", false }, { "pt2", false },
                                { "pt3", false }, { "pt4", false },

                        };

                        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

                        table.setModel(model);

                    }
                }
            });
```

This is my tableChanged:

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {


                if ((Boolean)table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1)) {


                    System.out.println(">\t"
                            + table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0));

                } else {

                    System.out.println(">\t"
                            + table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0));
                }

            }
        });
```

I do not understand why the event is not fired after updating the model. Am I updating the table incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You area creating a new `TableModel` but you added the `ChangeListener` to the old `TableModel`.

Don't create a new TableModel!

You can clear the data by using `setRowCount(0)`.

The you can add the new data back to the `DefaultTableModel` by using:

1. the `setDataVector(...)` method, or
2. by adding data back to the model one row at a time using the `addRow(...)` method.

So there is no need to create a new TableModel. If you want to create a new TableModel then you also need to add your ChangeListener to this new model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you said:This is what I have now:

       
     model.setRowCount(0);     
     model.setDataVector(data1, columnNames1);
     //model.fireTableDataChanged();
     table.setModel(model);
      

On model.setRowCount(0) the addTableModelListener is triggered and at this line 
if ((Boolean) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1)) {

exception is thrown:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I tried switching the model.fireTableDataChanged();. It does not make any difference.

Comment: I just want to update the data on combo box selection change and use the tableChanged to pull rowdata when the checkboxes in the second column are checked

Comment: @user1472972, You should NEVER manually invoke any `fireXXX(...)` method. That is the job of the TableModel. There is no need to invoke setModel() since you haven't changed the model. All you need to do is change the data in the model using the two statements I suggested.